# May I call std::terminate directly?

Tags: c++, oop, exception

I have a non-void function which returns a value to be used as an input of a class constructor, but there is a possibility for that value not to be available, so I want to return the value in case of success or just terminate (`std::terminate()`) the application in case of failure before the function return.

Since `std::terminate` is called by the `runtime` according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate, am I obliged to `throw an exception` and let the runtime decide whether the program is terminated or not?

What about the following warning I read in a simple test I just performed? `"terminate called without an active exception"`

Am I going in a stupid way?

Thanks for your insights in advance!

Comment: *> `std::terminate()` may also be called directly from the program.*

Comment: I didn't know that, is there any possibility of side effects?

Comment: The cppreference page you linked has this on it: *std::terminate() may also be called directly from the program.*

Comment: Well it's an abrupt and immediate termination. It doesn't unwind stacks, it doesn't allow for any kind of cleanups, or for threads to cleanly exits. Depending on operating system it might leave large resource leaks.

Comment: Is this a `sigkill(kill -9)` instead a `sigterm (kill -7`)?

Comment: `std::terminate()` is neither a `sigkill(kill -9)` nor a `sigterm(kill -7)`.  It's not a signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... I obliged to throw an exception and let the runtime decide whether the program is terminated or not?

It is up to you. If you want to be able for an exception to be caught somewhere up the call stack then you should throw an exception. In cases you want to terminate because there is no way to recover then calling `std::terminate` is fine. Just consider that if you throw an exception which is not caught then the program terminates anyhow, so you can choose to either catch it or not, while `std::terminate` terminates always.

Answer (score 3):

The same page that you linked to, in your question, also has the following statement:

> std::terminate() may also be called directly from the program.

Comment: I'm sorry for not reading the page very carefully. Thanks a lot for you point. I performed a simple test before going to this approach and I saw the following warning: `terminate called without an active exception`

Comment: If you're calling `terminate()` in order to bail out, and cut your losses, then an extra warning doesn't seem to matter much to me. Your program did terminate, didn't it?

Comment: Yes, it did terminate.